# How can I find the max value from each column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL, so this could be a trivial question. I have a table that has data like this:

```
State: varchar(30)
Year_06: varchar(10)
Year_07: varchar(10)
Year_08: varchar(10)
```

| State | Year_06 | Year_07 | Year_08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| State_1 | 991 | 01 | 37 |
| State_2 | 341 | 11 | 57 |
| State_3 | 551 | 41 | NA |

Now, I have to find the max value for states for each year. So, for `Year_06`, the answer would be `State_1`, and so on.

I tried sorting the output in descending order by using

```
SELECT * from table_name order BY Year_06::int desc;
```

This shows the output like this:

| State | Year_06 | Year_07 | Year_08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| State_1 | 991 | 01 | 37 |
| State_3 | 551 | 41 | NA |
| State_2 | 341 | 11 | 57 |

But, I want to show the highest value for each state for each year. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: There is some abiguity in your question as to what your expected results should actually be, and what happens if there are duplicate values? It would be useful to actually show us.

Comment: Poor table design. Have the columns state, year and "value" instead.

Comment: Specify the expected result!

Comment: What is `'NA'` and why is it stored in a column that looks like a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would unpivot and reaggregate:

```
select distinct on (v.year) v.year, v.val, t.state
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('Year_06', year_06),
             ('Year_07', year_07),
             ('Year_08', year_08)
     ) v(year, val)
order by v.year, v.val desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e23f58dda2bd1ae7b0ac88217c449e1) is a db<>fiddle.

The above assumes that the values in the columns are *numbers* and that `NA` really means `NULL`.  If the values are string, you will need to either sort them as strings or convert them to numbers, something like:

```
select distinct on (v.year) v.year, v.val, t.state
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('Year_06', year_06),
             ('Year_07', year_07),
             ('Year_08', year_08)
     ) v(year, val)
where v.val <> 'NA'
order by v.year, v.val::int desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(State) OVER (ORDER BY NULLIF(Year_06, 'NA')::int DESC NULLS LAST) State_06,
       FIRST_VALUE(State) OVER (ORDER BY NULLIF(Year_07, 'NA')::int DESC NULLS LAST) State_07,
       FIRST_VALUE(State) OVER (ORDER BY NULLIF(Year_08, 'NA')::int DESC NULLS LAST) State_08
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fd30e2f387e3d456c84fc26c5e61a9df).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something you need:

```
select A.State, Year_06
       , B.State, Year_07
       , C.State, Year_08 
from
(select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by Year_06 desc) rn
, State, Year_06
from test t) A
left join
(select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by Year_07 desc) rn
, State, Year_07
from test t) B on A.rn = B.rn
left join 
(select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by Year_08 desc) rn
, State, Year_08
from test t) C on B.rn = C.rn
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=577c762ed1100b81fd93d9113deea82e)